# How to automate file handling in python

Tags: python, automation, file-handling

This is my code

```
f1 = open("file1.txt").read( ).splitlines( )
f2 = open("file2.txt").read( ).splitlines( )
print list(itertools.product(f1,f2))
```

I want to run this for all files in the directory.How to do it using python. I am unable to implement suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038764/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-on-many-files-to-get-many-output-files/44919594#44919594) using glob.

Comment: ever heard about for loops ?

Comment: Just loop through each file in the directory using os.listdir()

Comment: What do you mean by *I am unable to implement suggestions given here using glob* - do you get errors? Please show what you have tried so far, including possible errors.

Comment: thanks @Krishan Mehta I know about for loops but I don't know to implement it in this context.We ask for suggestions here kindly don't try to mock at others just because u know something which they don't know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import glob

#For any kind of file in that directory.

for file in list(glob.glob("*")):     
    # do your work

#For specific kind of file in that directory. like all .py or .txt or .csv file.. etc. 

for file in list(glob.glob("*.file extension")):
    # do your work
```